# XCode 7.3.1 Update Not Installing

Tags: xcode, app-store

It looks like XCode came out with a new update. This issue seems to be persistent where the iTunes Store does not render the update even though it posts it in the "Updates Installed in Last 30 Days" section. After I restart, I am then prompted to update again even though I have already done it twice. Ultimately, the update does not apply when I open XCode (it still shows 7.3, not 7.3.1):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Delete the existing Xcode app and download 7.3.1 from the Apple Developer Site.

Comment: @trojanfoe I have used the manual method when I had this issue prior, although downloading from the Apple Developer Site sorted the problem for me, the `App Store` still had the app listed as 'installed' for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is only one way! For this you need:
1. Delete the XCode 7.3 from Applications folder
2. Download the Xcode 7.3.1 from [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) 
[image] 
3. install it manually
That's it))

Comment: Is this a common issue that users experience?

Comment: not really, but sometimes it happens, like today with me too)

Comment: @tccpg288 I have had this issue as well.

Comment: This answer is not exactly right; there is NOT only one way. The problem is that AppStore updates take a while to be available due to Apple's internal process. For users that can not wait, this answer is correct. However, by now the 7.3.1 update has become generally available to the AppStore, hence a normal update via AppStore is possible now.

Comment: I had to do this due to XCode 8 beta being installed... alternative path could be to delete XCode 8 then install Xcode 8 again after the update, however I had a fast net connection so I just downloaded 7.3.1 in full.

Answer (score 2):

A possible method of resolving this issue which has worked for people including myself, is as follows:

Close App Store.
Using terminal type the following:

```
    open $TMPDIR/../C
```

Locate and then delete the folder named `com.apple.appstore`
Empty Trash folder, if you get an error message saying that files are in use try the following:

```
    sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash/*
```

Restart Mac.

Once you have restarted your Mac try to install the update.

If this does not work delete `Xcode` from `/Applications` and repeat the above method.