# Xcode 7.3.1 update stuck? is it downloading?

Tags: xcode, app-store

Trying to download Xcode 7.3.1 but download process is stuck for atleast 1 - 1/2 hour, is it stuck, is it going to complete? I have latest Mac OS installed

Tried solution provided on this link but non worked
 [XCode 7.3.1 Update Not Installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37030672/xcode-7-3-1-update-not-installing)

[image: Stuck with this process for hours!!!!]

Comment: Seriously, why -ve vote? None of solution provided on stack overflow works!

Comment: This question is off-topic here. This is not a programming question. Try posting on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: wow - so may -ve votings. Is't this a programming question as it impacts directly my ability to use Xcode to use it on latest iPhone. If you search stack overflow there are many people posted similar questions with no concrete answers. None of them given any -ve voting. Such -ve votings makes you feel not to participate or ask questions

Comment: This is not a programming question. It's a question about installing a piece of software. Just because the software happens to be Xcode doesn't make it a programming question. And the down votes simply mean that the question isn't useful (since it's off topic). It's not personal. And any other similar questions are also off topic.

Comment: I'll make a note of that.. Here is interesting search http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xcode+7.3.1+download   none of questions rated -ve, except mine

Comment: StackOverflow says it's off-topic if it's not related to programming, **unless** it's about a program or tool that is related  to programming, which is this case. So no off-topic

Comment: @VladimirNul That is only true if it's about using the software. This is a simple case of installing software. Just because the software is about installing Xcode doesn't make it a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always happens to me (Well, not always but it happens, and also with another apps). What I do is to delete the Xcode app, and then install it again from the App Store or from the Developer's site.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try that. At least you tried to help me.. so many -ve voting with no help :(

Comment: So after keeping it running for more than 12 hours and praying. Finally update process is complete. @VladimirNul thanks much for your constructive feedback rather than just giving -ve votes